# Convert query with ISODate

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this MongoDB query:

```
db.Certificates.countDocuments(
  {"vaccination.somministration_date":ISODate("2021-08-04")}
)
```

and I want to perform it also in my java application, so I tried this code:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-08-04");
Bson query = eq("vaccination.somministration_date", date);
long count = collection.countDocuments(query);
```

But the results I get are different (from mongo I have 1 as result, while having 0 from java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB stores datetimes in GMT+0.  Your first query in Javascript is calling `ISODate()` which always produces a datetime with GMT+0 ("Z"ulu) time offset.
It is likely that your Java exec environment in calling `parse()` is taking local time offset into account and creating a slightly different datetime.